# Lag spike when opening windows Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ram, lag

I'm experiencing the issue that the RAM usage of my software spikes whenever I open a new window inside my software and the window opens delayed and somewhat laggy. This issue strangely enough only occured since I started using x64 only builds. After switching back to AnyCPU builds the issue persisted though. I've no idea what was changed when I switched to x64.

[Image of lag spikes when opening windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmDiG.png)

I've tried everything, using a different OS, machine, VS2019 instead of VS2022, nothing worked. I even tried swapping out files of my software with older files where the lag spikes didn't occur and this didn't help either.

After some more debugging I found out that it has almost certainly something to do with the Icon as the software loads perfectly fine without it.

Comment: What kind of *Window* would that be? What GUI Platform (add the Tag)? -- Post the code that is run when you initialize and load your Window.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with .NET, memory usage drops without the garbage collector running.  You *might* get a cue from seeing what DLLs get loaded, visible in the Output window with unmanaged debugging enabled.

Comment: @Jimi I'm using Winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer myself after hours of debugging and searching and it may be a little emberrassing that I didn't notice this earlier.

So you see, the software lagged whenever an Icon was loaded. This was because the Icon was a **5000x5000px** image.

After scaling the image down to **128x128px** everything works fine.
So if anyone is experiencing this or a similar issue - check your image files first :).